# Read all .pdf files in directory; Extract fillable fields to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, glob, pypdf

I have am writing a script that reads a folder of .pdfs and extracts their fillable fields to a pandas df. I had success extracting one .pdf with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import glob, os

pwd = os.getcwd()

pdfFileObj = open('pdf_filename', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

fields_dict = pdfReader.getFormTextFields()
series = pd.Series(fields_dict).to_frame()
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(fields_dict)).T
```

I want to build a function that runs this script for all pdfs in the directory. My first idea was to use a function in glob that collects all pdfs. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import glob, os

pwd = os.getcwd()

def readfiles():
   os.chdir(pwd)
   pdfs = []
   for file in glob.glob("*.pdf"):
       print(file)
       pdfs.append(file)

pdfFileObj = open(readfiles, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

fields_dict = pdfReader.getFormTextFields()
series = pd.Series(fields_dict).to_frame()
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(fields_dict)).T
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because I cannot put a function in the pdfFileReader. Does anyone have suggestions on a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What does your single pdf dataframe look like?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, new account. But you could try making your readFiles function return the array pdfs.

Then in code execution below just:

```
listofPDF=readfiles()
arrayofDF=list()
for file in listofPDF:
       pdfFileObj = open(file , 'rb')
       pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
       ##execute your code to obtain a single dataframe from a pdf here
       fields_dict = pdfReader.getFormTextFields()
       series = pd.Series(fields_dict).to_frame()
       df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(fields_dict)).T
       arrayofDF.append(df)
```

You would end up having a list of dataframes, each one corresponding to one of the pdf files, if the  first part of the code ( in which you get the dataframe from the singular pdf file) works.

Additionally, you could make a dictionary like {filename:file , dataframe: df} and then append that to your list, so you can later recover the dataframe based of the name of the file. It all depends on what you plan to do with the dataframes later.

Comment: Oh wow, that's an interesting take! Thanks! Unfortunately I am getting the error 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'... possibly because I have some Null values in my dicts?

Comment: That might be the case. Depending if you want those nulls, you could just filter the adding of those
if( [value of dictonary] != null]
     arrayofDF.append(df)

Then you could make sure that the final dict wont have zeroes or nulls.

Another question is, why are you getting those in the first place? the filenames shouldn't be nulls, are the steps leading to the creation of the dataframes able to output a null? I replied on the assumption that the part of getting the actual df was valid, since the question was not towards it. Either ways, try the above, or  leave me a comment.